# How to solve this error of pluggin of gradle?

Tags: flutter, dart

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX3381 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':wakelock' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

How to solve this error. I try all of steps like pub clean,pub get and pub upgrade. i will also do restart laptop as well as android studio but this error is still happen. pls help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin do you have?

Answer (score 0):

On you project navigate to `android\build.gradle`. On top of the file verify the value of `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'`.
And also the below dependencies

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
```